# Sending broadcast from one process to another process

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, ipc

This is my requirement.

I have an application which can be force kill by user. I want this application to receive broadcast from other app to execute some task even it is forced kill.

I am trying to make another app with service which will send a broadcast in event 1 mins to my first application.

My first application should receive this broadcast even it is forced kill.

This is what I am trying to do.

in First app:

```
    BroadcastReceiver dummy = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("broadcast Received","broadcast Received");
    }
};

 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.action.blockapp");
    registerReceiver(dummy,filter);
```

In my second app.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.action.blockapp");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        intent.setPackage("com.example.myapplication2");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I am not able to receive the broadcast when my app is forced kill.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

My point . You need to declare revice in the service running in the background. Your specific revice declared in the manifest`<receiver android:name=".service.NotifyReceiver" />
    </application>`

When the service is run. You can get notifications from revice like below

`Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NotifyReceiver.class);
intent1.setAction(action);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

Hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You have registered your `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically, in code. When your app is force stopped, that code is no longer running and your `BroadcastReceiver` no longer exists. It is no longer registered.

You will need to create a proper class that `extends BroadcastReceiver` and create a manuifest entry `<receiver>` for that with an `<intent-filter>` that matches the broadcast `Intent` you are broadcasting.